# Как получить сообщение от пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Требуется получить сообщение от пользователя, но убрать команду отправляющую само сообщение.

Чтобы получилось примерно так

```
Сообщение: /Message Привет!
Вывод: Привет!
```

Я пытался реализовать эту функцию как-то так..

```
user_msg = "{0}".format(message.text)
print(user_msg.split("/Message")[1])
```

Однако из-за того, что в .split нельзя добавить несколько команд приходится делать одинаковую функцию с разными командами в  `user_msg`. Хотя сам вывод получается полностью чистым, то есть без разных скобочек/ковычек. Как я могу получить такой же результат без `.split`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вы можете воспользоваться регулярными выражениями, чтобы удалять всё после `/` и до пробела.

```
import re
re.sub(r'/.* ', '', message.text)
```

например если `message.text` = `/Message Привет!` на выходе получим только `Привет!`

https://regex101.com/r/prxlwf/1

Comment: Регулярное выражение автора удалит весь текст, который начинается на "/" и заканчивается пробелом. Во избежание ошибок, рекомендую уточнить регулярное выражение так, чтобы вхождение искалось только вначале строки, а так же вместо маски ".*" искались только цифры\латинские буквы: 

`re.sub(r'^\/\w+ ', '', message.text)`

Answer (score 1):

Еще через описанные выше регулярные выражения можно сделать проще:

```
import re
msg = re.split(r' ', message.text, maxsplit=1)
msg.pop(0)
```

В этом коде вы делите сообщение по первому пробелу, т.е если текст сообщения = `/Message Привет, бот!`
То вы получаете список `msg = ['/Message', 'Привет, бот!]` и следующим действием `msg.pop(0)` удаляете `msg[0]` которое равно `/Message`, а дальше делаете с новым `msg[0]` (привет, бот!) что хотите.

P.S. если вы сделаете этим способом, то обьязательно сделайте структуру `try/except`, иначе при вводе `/Message` без текста, будет получена ошибка `IndexError` и бот отключится.